# how to access different forms through a loop and change label text in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, label

I have made a vb.net application which has 63 forms. On each form `label2` should contain the username using the application. The first form displayed to the user is the login form. When the user clicks the login button on this form the user name in all newly opened windows should appear inside `label2`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would strongly suggest to change the names of your controls and labels to something more maintainable in the future like userLabel.

**Edit:**

When your login form display you don't have the other windows open, so for your application they don't exist (yet) and hence you cannot loop through them or change state.

Since you have a large number of form you should try to find a solution that doesn't require a lot of repetive code. Others suggested MDI windows, which can be a solution. Another solution would be a custom login user-control that you create.

Such a custom control is not difficult to create. You can style it like you want and even add more functionality later when needed (like a logout link). In the Load-event of this user control you can retrieve the logged in user name (via static property or other mechanism) and display it inside.

With this the only thing you have to do is place this user control in all forms that should display the user-name and the rest works automatic. For help on how to create user controls there are a lot of tutorials in google and it's basically like creating a form.

Comment: Login FOrm is the first form and just one form is visible at a time...The functionality that i want is just to display the username, as label.text, who has signed in the application...I want the label text to be set at all the forms when the user logs in

Comment: Okay, I added some information that can help you to my response. I also edited your question a bit to add the information you just told me and make it more easy for others to understand what you need. Once you are satisfied with one answer please mark it as an accepted answer. This helps other with similar problems and rewards the people who helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the design requires a label in each form, you may want to consider using a form that is an MDI container as your main form, adding a status bar to the bottom of this form, and storing the user name in one of the status bar fields.

This way the user information is available in one location that the user knows about, you don't take up valuable screen real estate with a label, and you don't have to be concerned about new forms.

If the design does need a label in each form, then your best bet is to create a base class that each of the forms inherits from. During the form Load event, you can use the Find method in the Form's Controls collection to find the label that holds the user name and set it (this assumes that the labels all have the same name).

For example:

```
Dim oLabel As Label

oLabel = TryCast(Me.Controls.Find("label2", True), Label)

If oLabel IsNot Nothing Then
  oLabel.Text = globalusername
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

A. I Strongly agree with aKzenT with respect to naming your controls in some consistent and easily recognizable fashion. One of the benefits of our modern, fast machines is that we can use descriptive names in our code for variables and classes. :-)

B. There are any number of ways to approach your problem. While looping through all 63 forms is one of them, it is hardly the most efficient, effective, or again, maintainable down the road.

C. Not sure how you are handling your login, so I am unsure what happens after the user clicks OK on your login form. Did you set up your own login handling, or are you using built-in authentication?

competent_tech is on the right track suggesting inheritance. Taking it a step further, you could use the My.Application feature to contain your global variable. Go to your project properties window/Application/View Application Events. You will see the following code file. Add the indicated code:

```
Namespace My

    Partial Friend Class MyApplication


        'Add THIS code block:
        Private _CurrentUserName As String = "Current User"
        Public Property CurrentUserName() As String
            Get
                Return _CurrentUserName
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _CurrentUserName = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Now, your login form can set the application variable like so:

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    My.Application.CurrentUserName = Me.UsernameTextBox.Text
    'YOUR LOGIN CODE HERE . . .
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Don't create the class within the My.Application module. Use Project/Add/New Class
Then create a NEW class (NOT within the My.ApplicationEvents Module!) which inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Label, as follows:

```
Public Class MyUserLabel
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Label

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Text = My.Application.CurrentUserName
    End Sub
End Class
```

You will need to Build the project before the MyUserLabel control is visible in the toolbox. After you build, the control will be available for you to drag to your form(s). Or you might be able to use a Find/REplace with the scope set to "entire project". Replace "label2" with "MyUserControl"

The code above will cause instances of MyUserLabel to set the .Text property for each instance to the value represented by the My.Application.CurrentUser variable upon initialization (even in design mode).

Then replace Label2 on all of your forms with MyUserLabel (You could probably accomplish this with Find and replace scoped to entire project).

Hope that helps.

Here is the code:

```
       Namespace My

' The following events are availble for MyApplication:
' 
' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    'Add THIS code block:
    Private _CurrentUserName As String = "Current User"
    Public Property CurrentUserName() As String
        Get
            Return _CurrentUserName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _CurrentUserName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Class MyUserLabel
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Label

        Public Sub New()
            Me.Text = My.Application.CurrentUserName
        End Sub
    End Class


End Class
```

End Namespace

Comment: i've tried this above code and after building the project i can't see the new control in the Tool Box....I've made the public class in a module named as mod1.....And also i want to mention that i'm using a custom made login form (designed by me) with two textboxes and login button

Comment: Look in the Errors List. Did the project build successfully? There is no reason the MyUSerLable shouldn't appear in the Toolbox. Usually in the "Components" or "YourProjectNamespace Components" along with the selection arrow.

Comment: Also, there is no reason you can't use a Public Module for your global variable, although again, I strongly recommend renaming such that your code is more easily used/maintained. However, the My.Application namespace is a more logical place to put it . . .

Comment: even after placing it in the My.Application Namespace it's not visible in toolbox

Comment: Placing the variable in the My.Application file has nothing to do with the UserControl showing up in the toolbox. Can you post your code? Also, what version of VS are you using?

Comment: Create the custom class FIRST. Then Build. THEN use it in your code. THe code snippets above worked perfectly for me . . . I am using VS 2010 Professional. Can't see any reason why this wouldn't work on earlier versions (although, I'm not certain user controls will work in the free/express version of VS).

Comment: You were adding the user control within the My namespace. Add a new class to the project, then build.

Comment: Are you using VS 2005 Express (the free version)?

Comment: Don't have that information....Installed from a CD not downloaded from Internet....The installer Wizard just says Visual Studio 2005....Nothing else

Comment: I was often having similar problems with visual studio in the past. especially earlier versions. I recommend you uninstalling your version of 2005 and install Visual Basic Express 2010 instead. There are a lot of nice additions in the last versions and the express version offers all functionality needed especially for beginners. Download is free here: http://www.microsoft.com/express